# How to merge two images in one?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

how can I merge canvas in one image ? I need do this because I want to save merge image.

Here is my code:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(50, 50);
wb.LoadJpeg(stream);
Image t = new Image();
t.Source = wb;
Canvas.SetLeft(t, 130);
Canvas.SetTop(t, 130);
canvas1.Children.Add(t);
```

So now I want to merge these two images into one and use my save function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Graphics.FromImage() and Graphics.DrawImage()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
// Pseudo ...
using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image1))
{
    gfx.DrawImage(image2, new Point(0, 0));
}

// image1 is now merged with image 2
```

Comment: I've read some information about it, but I can't add namespace System.Drawing ? Windows Phone

Comment: Windows Phone does not support Graphics like that.  Graphics (g), is a Windows Form thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified in details what do you mean by "merge". Do you mean, overlay the images on top of each other (if that's the case, what overlay mode? add? multiply? normal?) or merge the images side by side into a larger image (like taking 3 shots with a camera and then combining them into one long photo)? Either way, you will want to look at the System.Drawing namespace.

Assuming the latter one is the case. Here's what you'll do:

```
Image a = ...;
Image b = ...;
//assuming equal height, and I forget whether the ctor is width first or height first
Image c = new Image(a.Width + b.Width, a.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(c);
g.DrawImage(...); //a lot of overloads, better check out the documentation
SaveImage(c); //depending on how you want to save it
g.Dispose();
```

Comment: I can't add System.Drawing namespace. Do you know what's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a third-party library, like [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). Look at the `Blit` method.